# How to make listview display full call logs?

Tags: android, listview, call

I want to make an activity display full info of call logs same the image below. I used Listview and ListAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter but i can not. Please tell me the way to make it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize ListView item and create your own adapter.
ex: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: Thank for reply. I saw your link and i read it, but my head felt muzzy. Can you demo for me a little code. Thank!

Comment: Create your own project and follow the instructions in that article please.